# Automatically fill vertical space for a description list in a beamer frame

Tags: beamer, description

I would like my description list to automatically fill the vertical space of a beamer slide. I have found solutions for this [here](https://pinjiahe.github.io/posts/2019/10/better-beamer), but it only applies to `itemize` and `enumerate`.

I tried to modify the examples in the list for a `description` list and it gives the desired effect for vertical spacing. However, the horizontal alignment alignment is incorrect. I cannot see the full description item because it is cut off on the left as shown in the image below.

I have provided the code for what I have tried so far below. Honestly, I get a little lost when I see `\makeatletter`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\description}[1][]{%
    \beamer@ifempty{#1}{}{\def\beamer@defaultospec{#1}}%
    \ifnum \@itemdepth >2\relax\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
    \beamer@computepref\@itemdepth% sets \beameritemnestingprefix
    \usebeamerfont{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body begin}%
    \list
    {\usebeamertemplate{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}}
    {\def\makelabel##1{%
            {%
                \hss\llap{{%
                        \usebeamerfont*{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
                        \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}##1}}%
            }%
        }%
    }
    \fi%
    \setlength\itemsep{\fill}
    \ifnum \@itemdepth >1
    \vfill
    \fi%  
    \beamer@cramped%
    \raggedright%
    \beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip%
}
\def\enditemize{\ifhmode\unskip\fi\endlist%
    \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body end}
    \ifnum \@itemdepth >1
    \vfil
    \fi%  
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Vertical Spacing}

    \begin{description}
        \item[description] details
        \item[description] vertical spacing is working
        \item[description] but descriptions are cut off  
    \end{description}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: maybe https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=832 can help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the same technique as in https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=832#a2071

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{s}[true]{% stretch
  \beamer@frametopskip=0pt\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskip=0pt\relax%
  \beamer@frametopskipautobreak=\beamer@frametopskip\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=\beamer@framebottomskip\relax%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[s]
\frametitle{Vertical Spacing}

    \begin{description}
        \item[description] details
        \item[description] vertical spacing is working
        \item[description] but descriptions are cut off  
    \end{description}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]